# MySQL varchar to number

Tags: mysql, sql, varchar, sql-types

I am trying a simple conversion - a mysql varchar column which contains longitude values (eg "-1.234" to -1.234) to enhance optimisation.

I have read and read on this and nothing works, last tried was:

```
UPDATE latlng_data SET lng_copy = CAST(lng AS DECIMAL(6,4));
```

met with:

> Error Code: 1366. Incorrect decimal value: '' for column '' at row -1

Target column, created to recover from errors is:

```
FLOAT(6,4)

and null allowed.
```

Why is mysql error messages so useless.

Following 'dognose' advice (below) I have used:

```
UPDATE latlng_data SET lng='999.9999' where lng='';-- to give invalid lng in this case
```

then increase the copy data field (with the aim to rename it orig) and then:

```
UPDATE latlng_data SET lng_copy = CAST(lng AS DECIMAL(7,4));
```

this appears to be required in mysql cmd as Workbench timesout but using:

```
show full processlist;
```

still shows it as running - so here the best monitor is cmd.

Comment: `CAST('-1.234' AS Decimal(6,4))`

Works just fine on my end ensure all values in lng_copy have values and can convert to Decimal(6,4) cleanly looks like one of them is ''

Comment: as @JasonSec says.  see: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/cast-functions.html  Possible dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18705119/mysql-how-to-convert-varchar-latitude-longitude-to-decimal-fields

Comment: `UPDATE latlng_data SET lng_copy = lng * 1` *... hides*

Comment: is there anyway to add a fallback if it cannot convert - this a millions row database, so if I can ignore and resource what is bad data at least I can proceed development while waiting.

Comment: thanks dognose, what would the result value be by doing that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checked this with:

```
SELECT * FROM t31data_happyenergy.latlng_data where lng_copy <> CAST(lng AS DECIMAL(7,4));
```

which now returns no results and can be better optimised as all are numerical, with bad data fully valued for a longitude.

I also recommend using a mysql command window as most apps timeout when extensive queries are used with this large data.

So basically the process went [ALWAYS CHECK BETWEEN EACH QUERY AS I GOT LAZY AND HAD TO START AGAIN AS ONE QUERY WAS WRONG):

```
-- convert all mostly read only tables to myisam:
-- dropped old lat and lng after checking same data by

SELECT count(*) FROM latlng_postcode where CAST(lat AS DECIMAL(7,4))!=latcopy;
SELECT count(*) FROM latlng_postcode where CAST(lng AS DECIMAL(7,4))!=lngcopy;

ALTER TABLE `latlng_postcode`
CHANGE COLUMN `latcopy` `lat` FLOAT(7,4) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
CHANGE COLUMN `lngcopy` `lng` FLOAT(7,4) NULL DEFAULT NULL;

-- then index (are these the best settings ??
ALTER TABLE `latlng_postcode` 
DROP INDEX `pcode` ,
ADD INDEX `pcode` USING BTREE (`postcode`(5) ASC),
ADD INDEX `lat` USING BTREE (`lat`(4) ASC),
ADD INDEX `lng` USING BTREE (`lng`(4) ASC);
```

Comment: thanks to all for replying, its seems dognose was on the right track and lead to checking if any rows exist that have an empty string - which seems to have been when it failed.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to convert numbers in MySQL is to use silent conversion.  That is, use the string in an arithmetic operation and any conversion errors are ignored.  A string with no numbers is interpreted as `0`:

```
UPDATE latlng_data
    SET lng_copy = lng + 0.0;
```

[Here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/type-conversion.html) is some relevant documentation.

EDIT:

If you are concerned about matching only correct values, then check the format of the string

```
WHERE lng rlike '[0-9]+[.]?[0-9]*'
```

Comment: Thanks, but in this case it results in a valid longitude value where there was one missing. This unfortunately would hide an error from being detected.