# Haversine distance calculation between two points in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, haversine

I'm working on a Laravel application in which I need to find all the products within a certain radius of the user's coordinates. Products have a one-to-many relationship with users so that users can have multiple products. I've found that the haversine algorithm can calculate the distance between two points, but I can't seem to make it work.

I've got the following query.

**Controller**

```
$latitude = 51.0258761;
$longitude = 4.4775362;
$radius = 20000;

$products = Product::with('user')
->selectRaw("*,
            ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians(" . $latitude . ") ) *
            cos( radians(user.latitude) ) *
            cos( radians(user.longitude) - radians(" . $longitude . ") ) + 
            sin( radians(" . $latitude . ") ) *
            sin( radians(user.latitude) ) ) ) 
            AS distance")
->having("distance", "<", $radius)
->orderBy("distance")
->get();
```

I've set the radius to 20000 for testing purposes, and it appears all products have a distance of 5687,... The problem seems to be that the latitude and longitude of the products are stored in the User table, but I'm not sure how I can access those in my query. I've tried *user.latitude* and *'user->latitude'*, but nothing seems to work.

**Product model**

```
class Product extends Model
{
    protected $fillable =
        [
            'soort',
            'hoeveelheid',
            'hoeveelheidSoort',
            'prijsPerStuk',
            'extra',
            'foto',
            'bio'
        ];

    public function User()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

    public $timestamps = true;
}
```

**User model**

```
use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\CanResetPassword;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\Authorizable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Access\Authorizable as AuthorizableContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword as CanResetPasswordContract;

class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract,
                                    AuthorizableContract,
                                    CanResetPasswordContract
{
    use Authenticatable, Authorizable, CanResetPassword;

    protected $table = 'users';

    protected $fillable = 
        [
        'firstName', 
        'lastName', 
        'adres',
        'profilepic',
        'description', 
        'longitude',
        'latitude',
        'email', 
        'password'
    ];

    protected $hidden = ['password', 'remember_token'];

    public function product()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Product');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 27):

This was my implementation of it. I've chosen to alias my query out ahead of time, this way I can take advantage of `Pagination`. Furthermore, you need to explicitly select the columns that you wish to retrieve from the query. add them at the `->select()`. Such as `users.latitude, users.longitude, products.name`, or whatever they may be.

I have created a scope which looks something like this:

```
public function scopeIsWithinMaxDistance($query, $location, $radius = 25) {

     $haversine = "(6371 * acos(cos(radians($location->latitude)) 
                     * cos(radians(model.latitude)) 
                     * cos(radians(model.longitude) 
                     - radians($location->longitude)) 
                     + sin(radians($location->latitude)) 
                     * sin(radians(model.latitude))))";
     return $query
        ->select() //pick the columns you want here.
        ->selectRaw("{$haversine} AS distance")
        ->whereRaw("{$haversine} < ?", [$radius]);
}
```

You can apply this scope to any model with a `latitude` and`longitude`.

Replace the `$location->latitude` with your `latitude` that you wish to search against, and replace the `$location->longitude` with the longitude that you wish to search against.

Replace the `model.latitude` and `model.longitude` with the Models you wish to find around the `$location` based on the distance defined in the `$radius`.

I know you have a functioning Haversine formula, but if you need to Paginate you can't use the code you've supplied.

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: hi thank you for your answer, I am wondering if radius is in kilometers or miles?

Comment: @Maxlight This would be for KM. For miles, you'd use `3961` instead of `6371`.

Comment: Great i needed km

Comment: `distance` column is not included in the result. how do I add that in the result?

Comment: @imrealashu Add it to the `select()`, we alias `{$haversine} as distance` so you can `select('distance')`

Comment: I tried that but that didn't work saying `distance` column doesn't exist. However I have `distance` in the raw query so it was available without even adding it in `select()` method. @Ohgodwhy

Comment: @imrealashu Yep, that's true! My fault on that one.

Comment: Hi @Ohgodwhy I am not knowing much about laravel or raw query is your answer safe enough? and yet some article told me its not safe to pass variable to the raw query

Comment: note: if you have the error saying `distance is not available` or something like that: its not working for postgres.

Comment: could you explain what the model.lat and model.long is for. What do I replace the `model` with?

Comment: @TimBogdanov These are the relative `latitude` and `longitude` of the models stored in your database in, what I would presume to be, `latitude` and `longitude` columns

Comment: @Ohgodwhy understood, another issue im facing is I'm getting this error: 

`: Undefined function: 7 ERROR: operator does not exist: bigint = character varying LINE 6: ...) AS distance from "addresses" where "users"."id" = "address... ^ HINT: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.`

I've research it for about an hour now, and cant seem to figure it out. From what it looks like I'm doing maths on a string and decimal. But don't know how to resolve it. Ive tried casting the users lat and long as a decimal but nothing.

Comment: this is what I got:
```$haversine = "(3961 * acos(cos(radians(cast($coordinates->latitude as decimal)))
                     * cos(radians(latitude))
                     * cos(radians(longitude)
                     - radians(cast($coordinates->longitude as decimal)))
                     + sin(radians(cast($coordinates->latitude as decimal)))
                     * sin(radians(latitude))))";```

Comment: @TimBogdanov Please see this question to understand the difficulties in casting lat/long VARCHAR values into DECIMAL types: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18705119/mysql-how-to-convert-varchar-latitude-longitude-to-decimal-fields

Answer (score 3):

Using Haversine method, you can calculate distance between two points using this function. It works but I don't  know how to implement this in Laravel. Thought of sharing this anyway.

```
$lat1 //latitude of first point
$lon1 //longitude of first point 
$lat2 //latitude of second point
$lon2 //longitude of second point 
$unit- unit- km or mile

function point2point_distance($lat1, $lon1, $lat2, $lon2, $unit='K') 
    { 
        $theta = $lon1 - $lon2; 
        $dist = sin(deg2rad($lat1)) * sin(deg2rad($lat2)) +  cos(deg2rad($lat1)) * cos(deg2rad($lat2)) * cos(deg2rad($theta)); 
        $dist = acos($dist); 
        $dist = rad2deg($dist); 
        $miles = $dist * 60 * 1.1515;
        $unit = strtoupper($unit);

        if ($unit == "K") 
        {
            return ($miles * 1.609344); 
        } 
        else if ($unit == "N") 
        {
        return ($miles * 0.8684);
        } 
        else 
        {
        return $miles;
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to use an external package instead, I suggest the infinitely useful PHPGeo library. I used it on a project that relied on these exact calculations, and it worked just fine. It saves you writing the calculations yourself from scratch and is tested to work.

https://github.com/mjaschen/phpgeo

Here is the documentation for Harvesine: https://phpgeo.marcusjaschen.de/#_distance_between_two_coordinates_haversine_formula

Comment: Thanks, but the haversine formula I used doesn't seem to be the problem. I just can't seem to figure out how I can access the latitude and longitude of the products which is stored in the owner (user) of the product, and not in the product itself

Comment: Perfect! This proved to be a simple and effective solution for my case. :-)

Answer (score 1):

This is a code I am using:

```
            $ownerLongitude = $request['longitude'];
            $ownerLatitude = $request['latitude'];
            $careType = 1;
            $distance = 3;

            $raw = DB::raw(' ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians(' . $ownerLatitude . ') ) * 
 cos( radians( latitude ) ) * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians(' . $ownerLongitude . ') ) + 
    sin( radians(' . $ownerLatitude . ') ) *
         sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) )  AS distance');
            $cares = DB::table('users')->select('*', $raw)
        ->addSelect($raw)->where('type', $careType)
        ->orderBy('distance', 'ASC')
        ->having('distance', '<=', $distance)->get();
```

Comment: Great explanation. Works as a charm

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is the [query builder to build a join](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries#joins). With a join you have the fields of both tables available in your query. Currently you are using [relationships with eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#eager-loading), this will preload the related users, but they cannot be used inside the SQL (Laravel will actually execute 2 queries).

Anyway I wouldn't try to calculate the haversine formula in one step with SQL, this cannot be really performant, and the query could become difficult to maintain in my opinion. This is what i would do instead:

1. Calculate an envelope with minimum/maximum of latitude and longitude, it should be a bit bigger than your search radius.
2. Make a fast query with a join of product and user, and just check whether the user location is inside this envelope.
3. For each element of the resulting list calculate the exact haversine distance with PHP (not SQL), delete rows which are outside the radius, and sort the list accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution in Laravel.

```
    public function near($myLon, $myLat, $areaLon, $areaLat)
{
    $this->applyCriteria();
    $this->applyScope();

    $results = $this->model->select(DB::raw("SQRT(
        POW(69.1 * (latitude - " . $myLat . "), 2) +
        POW(69.1 * (" . $myLon . " - longitude) * COS(latitude / 57.3), 2)) AS distance, SQRT(
        POW(69.1 * (latitude - " . $areaLat . "), 2) +
        POW(69.1 * (" . $areaLon . " - longitude) * COS(latitude / 57.3), 2)) AS area"), "YOUR_TABLE.*")->get();

    $this->resetModel();
    $this->resetScope();

    return $this->parserResult($results);
}
```

The answer is in Miles, you will have to replace YOUR_TABLE with the name of your database table.
Thank you hope it helps