# Perform query on a calculated column using Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I want to perform the following SQL statement in PHP using Laravel's Eloquent model:

```
SELECT *, (3959 * acos(cos(radians(37)) * cos(radians(lat)) * cos(radians(lng) - radians(-122)) + sin(radians(37)) * sin(radians(lat )))) AS distance
FROM example_retailers
HAVING distance < 1000
ORDER BY distance
OFFSET 4
LIMIT 3;
```

I am struggling to translate this into a Laravel's Eloquent Model (mainly the calculated column).

This is what I have so far:

```
ExampleRetailer::
    // TODO: add calculated row
    where('distance', '<', 100)
    ->orderBy('distance')
    ->skip(4)
    ->limit(3)
    ->get();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Haversine distance calculation between two points in Laravel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37876166/haversine-distance-calculation-between-two-points-in-laravel)

Comment: @Clive That question does not tell me how to do it using the eloquent class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use raw queries ([source](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#raw-expressions) )

```
DB::table('example_retailers')
->select(DB::raw('*, (3959 * acos(cos(radians(37)) * cos(radians(lat)) * cos(radians(lng) - radians(-122)) + sin(radians(37)) * sin(radians(lat )))) AS distance'))
->having('distance', '<', 100)
->orderBy('distance')
->skip(4)
->limit(3)
->get();
```

Comment: I get an error when running this: `unknown column 'distance'`

Comment: You made a small mistake. It should be `having`, not `where`.

Comment: How would I do it using the eloquent class? I updated the question to make this more clear.

Answer (score -1):

If it's only to make a new row using SQL:

```
SELECT *, CASE WHEN (3959 * acos(cos(radians(37))
                          * cos(radians(lat))
                          * cos(radians(lng) - radians(-122))
                          + sin(radians(37))
                          * sin(radians(lat )))) < 100 THEN END AS NewRow
FROM example_retailers
```

Comment: Thats not even in Laravel