# implementing haversine distance query based on lng and lat

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, haversine

I have run into a problem when developing this.

I have this scope function implemented that I run on the model like

Listing::closest($lat, $lng)->paginate(5);

```
public function scopeClosest($query, $lat, $lng, $distance = 0, $units = 'km')
{

    switch ( $units ) {
        case 'miles':
            //radius of the great circle in miles
            $gr_circle_radius = 3959;
        break;
        case 'km':
            //radius of the great circle in kilometers
            $gr_circle_radius = 6371;
        break;
    }

    return $query->selectRaw(
        '*, ( '.$gr_circle_radius.' * acos( cos( radians('.$lat.') ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians('.$lng.') ) + sin( radians('.$lat.') ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance'
    )->havingRaw("distance < ?", [10] );

}
```

However I run into this error that I do not now how to fix

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'distance' in 'having clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `listings` having distance < 10)

It seems that laravel is running 2 queries, this is how it looks if I do not use havingRaw()

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => array:3 [▼
    "query" => "select count(*) as aggregate from `listings`"
    "bindings" => []
    "time" => 0.48
  ]
  1 => array:3 [▼
    "query" => "select *, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(37) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(-122) ) + sin( radians(37) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance from `listings` limit 5 offset 0"
    "bindings" => []
    "time" => 0.97
  ]
]
```

When I use havingRaw it seems laravel applies it to the first query and ofcourse it will fail. But why does it apply it to the first query and not the second one?

Comment: what is your requirement, can you please explain a bit? Do you want to get closest 5 locations based on given latitude and longitude?

Comment: 5 is just example, i need this paginated

Comment: [You may enjoy my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37877412/1206267).

Comment: If it was me, I'd just run the query and let the user decide if the result should be displayed in km, miles, leagues, chains, or whatever - in JavaScript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I did in my case .. I need to query  distance which were in 5 kms radius . I used `whereRaw` along with `paginate`

```
$vtl = VehicleTrackerLog::whereRaw("(
                                    111.1111 
                                    *DEGREES(ACOS(COS(RADIANS('-33.873415'))
                                    * COS(RADIANS(lat))
                                    * COS(RADIANS('151.227538' - lng))+ SIN (RADIANS('-33.873415'))         
                                    * SIN(RADIANS(lat))))<=5)"
                                    )->paginate(5);
```

**If you want in Miles simply multiply by 69.041236 instead of 111.111**

Comment: I haven't tried this yet but it looks great, to also offer miles as unit what do I substitute 111.1111 with?

Comment: For miles, divide km by 1.609344

Comment: so "<= 5/1.609344"?